# Hide the lines in my pivot table in my field “vendor” which contain the word “JVPDML”

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table and I would like  in my field called “vendor”, all vendor which contains the word “JVPDLM” are hidden…
I saved this macro below but I can still have more vendor in future subject to contain this word “JVPDLM”, that´s why my list in my VBA code below is not exhaustive.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Xavi

```
Sub hideJVPDMLcompanycode()
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Vendor")
.PivotItems("JVPDML Espana ").Visible = False
.PivotItems("JVPDML International GmbH ").Visible = False
.PivotItems("JVPDML GmbH ").Visible = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for each` to check each `PivotItem` on contains `*JVPDML*` pattern, here example:

```
Sub hideJVPDMLcompanycode()
    Dim pItem As PivotItem
    For Each pItem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Vendor").PivotItems
        If UCase(pItem.Value) Like "*JVPDML*" Then pItem.Visible = False
    Next pItem
End Sub
```

*test:*

[image]